# Getting rid of excess while statement

Tags: java, while-loop

Could anybody have a look at this snippet of code and and tell me if there is a way to amalgamate the two while statements into one?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader fileInput;
    fileInput = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("information.txt"));
    int countOfClients = 0;
    while (fileInput.ready())
    {
        fileInput.readLine();
        countOfClients ++;
    }
    int totalClients = countOfClients ;

    Client[] clientDetails = new Client[totalClients];
    int clientNumber = 0;

    while (fileInput.ready())
    {
        String currentLineOfText = fileInput.readLine();
        String clientName = currentLineOfText.substring(0, 19);
        String gender = currentLineOfText.substring(20,21);
        char clientGender = gender.charAt(0);
        int clientAge = Integer.parseInt(currentLineOfText.substring(22,24));
        String clientInterests = currentLineOfText.substring(25);
        clientDetails[clientNumber] = new Client(clientName, clientGender, clientAge, clientInterests);
        clientNumber++;
    }
```

The first while statement is reading all the lines in the text, so it knows how many elements in the object array it needs.
The array clientDetails of class Client[] is then created.
The second while statement populates that array.
Can I avoid using two while statements?

Note: This is for an assignment and I have to use arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of an array and simply use:

```
list.add(new Client(...));
```

If you really need an array, you can always call:

```
Client[] array = list.toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks assylias. Is there any other way to get around this? I have no experience of ArrayLists and while I am more than willing to learn, this is for a university practical and I don't want to do something that my lecturer thinks is over the top! He stated he wants an array of a class (as we've just covered it), so I think I have to stick with it.

Comment: In that case you only have 3 options I believe: (i) create an array large enough to hold what you think should be the maximum size - but if your file is larger than you thought you are in trouble or (ii) create an array of a certain size, when it is full, create a new, larger, array, copy the full array to the new array etc. (iii) keep your approach. Note that option (ii) is exactly what arraylist does under the hood.

Comment: Thanks for your response. And thanks for editing my post, I was in the middle of doing it myself when I saw you had done it much more succinctly! The array is a list of clients looking for dates and they are matched up by a set of criteria. We know the array has 20 lines, so I originally just set a final int of 20. I was just looking for a way that would stand alterations (although this isn't really necessary). As such, I'll just go back to using the final int.

Comment: @AndrewMartin If you have just started Java, this is a reasonable approach and probably what you teacher expects. To make it a touch fancier, you could add a check that the counter does not exceed your array size. If it does, print an error message and exit your loop. That way you make sure you won't get an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: no, simply an if: `countOfClients ++; if(countOfClients > array.length) { System.err.println("Too many lines in the file"); break;}`

Comment: Brilliant, I'll use that. Thanks so much, you're a star!

Comment: Answer chosen as it discusses techniques OTHER than an ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

As they're all saying, use an ArrayList to store the items.

If memory is an issue, you can use ArrayList.toArray() to trim it down to the bare bones.

If efficiency is an issue, you probably shouldn't be reading from a file in the first palce.

Answer (score 0):

Why create an array ? Why not have one `while` loop that creates an `ArrayList` and then (if you *need* an array) extract the resultant array from that using [ArrayList.toArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) ?

Comment: Thanks Brian. Is there any other way to get around this? I have no experience of ArrayLists and while I am more than willing to learn, this is for a university practical and I don't want to do something that my lecturer thinks is over the top! He stated he wants an array of a class (as we've just covered it), so I think I have to stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid two while loops by changing `Client[]` to ArrayList();

Example:

```
List<Client> clientDetails = new ArrayList<Client>();
    int clientNumber = 0;

    while (fileInput.ready())
    {
        String currentLineOfText = fileInput.readLine();
        String clientName = currentLineOfText.substring(0, 19);
        String gender = currentLineOfText.substring(20,21);
        char clientGender = gender.charAt(0);
        int clientAge = Integer.parseInt(currentLineOfText.substring(22,24));
        String clientInterests = currentLineOfText.substring(25);
        clientDetails.add( new Client(clientName, clientGender, clientAge, clientInterests));
    }
```

Note: Hand edited, there may be syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't use the pre-written ArrayList class, you could always effectively re-implement it (or at least the relevant bits of it) yourself.

The key technique is to take a guess at the size of the array you might need, define an array that size, and, if you find it is too small, create a bigger array and copy all the existing values from the old to the new array, before continuing in the space that is left over.

At the other end of the loop, you might be in for yet another step, and shrink the array again (by declaring a smaller array and copying values over) so you have no empty spaces left.

Or, as recommended by all the other answers, just use an ArrayList, which already does exactly this for you...