# Rewriting nested for loops to give better formatted output

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, nested-loops

The following is code from a university practical I am doing. It reads in a txt file of twenty clients, whose information is stored in the txt file like this:

```
Sophia Candappa     F 23 00011
```

As per my lecturer's instructions, I have stored this information in a class called Client (although I know an ArrayList would be better I can't use it).
The code below is a method that is used to compare all the clients to one another and determine if they are a match. They are a match if they are all of the following:

1. Opposite sex
2. Age within five years of one another
3. They have three interests in common

The latter is determined by the string "00011" in the example above. If the clients share the number "1" at the same place in the string on three or more occasions, then the third condition is satisfied.

My code works perfectly and outputs the desired result. However, I want to ask two questions.

- Is it as efficient as it could be (without ArrayLists)? I had considered separating out all the if/else statements into separate methods, but decided against it as I thought it wouldn't reduce any of the actual loops.
- How can I change the output slightly. Currently, if a client is matched it displays "[Client Name] is compatible with" then it takes a new line and outputs all the clients who are matched. I would like to change it so that if the client has just one match, it says "Client Name is compatible with"..., but if the client has two or more clients it says "Client Name is compatible with the following [two/three/four] clients...

I have tried doing the latter, but I always mess up the formatting. Thanks in advance for any help that can be offered.

```
public static void matchClients(Client[] clientDetails)
{
    boolean anyMatch;
    int count;
    for (int b = 0; b < numberOfClients; b++)
    {
        anyMatch = false;
        count = 0;
        for (int c = 0; c < numberOfClients; c++)
        {
            if (clientDetails[b].getClientGender()!=clientDetails[c].getClientGender())
            {
                if (Math.abs(clientDetails[b].getClientAge() - clientDetails[c].getClientAge()) <= 5)
                {
                    int interests = 0;

                    String clientOneInterests = clientDetails[b].getClientInterests();
                    String clientTwoInterests = clientDetails[c].getClientInterests();

                    int interestNumber = 0;
                    while (interestNumber < clientOneInterests.length())
                    {
                        if ((clientOneInterests.charAt(interestNumber) == clientTwoInterests.charAt(interestNumber))
                                && (clientOneInterests.charAt(interestNumber) == '1' ))
                            interests++;
                        interestNumber++;
                    }

                    if (interests >= 3)
                    {
                        anyMatch = true;
                        if (count == 0)
                        {
                            System.out.println(clientDetails[b].getClientName() + "is compatible with the following client(s)");
                            System.out.println("\t" + clientDetails[c].getClientName());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("\t" + clientDetails[c].getClientName());
                        }
                        count++;
                    }
                    interests = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        if (anyMatch == false)
            System.out.println(clientDetails[b].getClientName() + "is not compatible with any client.");
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418880/getting-rid-of-excess-while-statement

Comment: If you don't want to use any Java features like collections, just use C++?

Comment: @Adam: I don't know how to use C++ and even if I did, I do have to use Java. I just can't use an ArrayList (instead it is an array of objects).

Comment: The point of separating out some of the code into separate methods isn't performance, but readability. You and everyone else will understand your code better if you split it up into smaller chunks.

Comment: @AlanStokes: I originally did that, and passed the relevant elements of the array in method calls (i.e. if compareGender method finds client genders aren't the same, pass array and two elements through to compareAge method). However, again I couldn't get good formatting on my output.

Comment: Split your code into two - start by working out all the matches for each client, and then have a function to print the set/list/array of matches in your desired format.

Comment: @AlanStokes: Thanks for this advice. I'll work on it now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So many stereotypes encoded in one small question!

For improving efficiency, there's nothing inherently wrong with your two loops. But it's generally better to look at the big picture (the algorithm) rather than the detail (loops, array vs ArrayList).

So, a few simple suggestions:

- Store male and female clients separately.
- Store clients in order of age, so you can quickly find the range of clients that are possible age matches (binary search vs linear search).
- Don't bother storing anyone with fewer than 3 interests.

For matching interests you have to work a bit harder, but there are things you could do if the number of clients is large (eg having a map from sets of interests to the clients with exactly those interests).

Comment: Thanks for all this. And yes, LOTS of stereotypes! My lecturer's instructions are: ...write a Java program which will read this information and store it in an array. For each of the dating agency’s clients you should print out the clients who are compatible with each other.

Comment: Therefore, as good as your ideas are, I think I have to store all clients, regardless of interests. The store clients in order of age sounds very interesting, but is it worth changing this? As they are currently stored by gender, will it not speed up the age comparison whilst slowing down the gender comparison?

Comment: For 20 clients it's not worth doing anything beyond the obvious tbh.

Comment: You could separately store the clients of each sex, each ordered by age - then you can make both comparisons quick. But again for small input not really a win.